# Problemas no JPA, @OneToOne e mappedBy

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho três classes, Pessoa, Cliente e Endereço, sendo Cliente filho de Pessoa e Endereço agregando Pessoa.

Segue Pessoa:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;
private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String email;
private String pw;
private String numeroEnd;
private String complementoEnd;

@OneToOne
public Endereco endereco;
```

Segue Endereço:

```
@Entity
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)    
private long   id;
private String cep;
private String logradouro;
private String bairro;
private String cidade;
private String uf;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Pessoa pessoa;
```

O erro que estou tendo é o seguinte:

> Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [LojaGamesPU] failed. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: The attribute [pessoa] in entity class [class br.com.lojagames.model.Endereco] has a mappedBy value of [post] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class br.com.lojagames.model.Pessoa]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.

Sou leigo em JPA porém gostaria de fazer para adquirir experiência, entretanto creio que eu fiz o relacionamento entre as classes no JPA de forma errada, poderiam me apontar o erro?

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann Exatamente, fiz e funcionou, muito obrigado, Paulo, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The attribute [pessoa] in entity class [class br.com.lojagames.model.Endereco] has a mappedBy value of [post] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class br.com.lojagames.model.Pessoa]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.

O parâmetro `mappedBy` deve ser usado quando há uma relação bidirecional, como é seu caso. Porém ele deve "mapear" a classe que o está chamando.

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "endereco", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Comment: Paulo, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!
Sem abusar de sua paciência, após eu cadastrar um CEP junto ao cliente ocorre o seguinte erro: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: br.com.lojagames.model.Endereco@4afb0d29.
Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Para uma relação bidirecional as duas classes devem ser atualizadas, para isso você deve utilizar o `CascadeType.PERSIST` ao invés do `ALL`, caso fique difícil compreender ou não resolva, bola uma nova pergunta com os detalhes que a comunidade vai te ajudar de novo.